# SIGWINCH and cout acting unreliably

Tags: c++, linux, unix, terminal, text-editor

I am trying to write a simple text editor in C++.

One of the features that I am trying to implement is dynamic resizing of the text when the window size changes. To do this, I am using a signal handler for `SIGWINCH` with `sigaction` which updates the number of rows and columns of a global `config` object as follows

```
void registerHandler() {
  struct sigaction resize;
  memset(&resize, '\0', sizeof(resize));
  resize.sa_handler = handleWINCH;
  sigaction(SIGWINCH, &resize, NULL);
}

void getTerminalSize() {
  winsize w;
  ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
  config.nCols = w.ws_col;
  config.nRows = w.ws_row;
}

void handleWINCH(int) {
  getTerminalSize();
  draw();
}
```

Right now, I am just displaying the number of columns stored in a global `config` object using the `draw` method, as such

```
void draw() {
  std::cout << ERASESCREEN << HOME << std::flush;
  std::cout << config.nRows;
}
```

The problem is that this code acts very unreliably. Sometimes it works and sometimes it crashes prematurely and outputs a "%" character for seemingly no reason.

The terminal is in raw mode, enabled with `cfmakeraw`

```
void enableRawMode() {
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &config.initalConfig);
  atexit(disableRawMode);

  termios raw = config.initalConfig;
  cfmakeraw(&raw);

  tcsetattr(STDERR_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}
```

`HOME` and `ERASESCREEN` are ANSI escape sequences to reset the cursor and clear the screen, defined as follows

```
#define ERASESCREEN "\x1b[2J"
#define HOME "\x1b[H"
```

Lastly, I enabled the `std::unitbuf` to hopefully mitigate any issues caused from the output buffering of `cout`.

```
  std::cout << std::unitbuf << HOME << ERASESCREEN <<std::flush;
```

Furthermore, I've noticed that this issue with outputting and signal handling only happens in raw mode. Otherwise, the program seems to respond to the WINCH signal normally. I suspect there might be an issue with the output stream, which is why I keep trying to flush manually, but I don't know C++ and UNIX programming well enough to be able to guess any further.

I've uploaded the full [code](https://github.com/LucaIgnatescu/SimpleTextEditor) as well in case I did not include something important.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `resize` lifetime ends when registerHandler returns so the pointer you gave to the signal handler is no longer valid.

Comment: I don't think you should be accessing `std::cout` from inside a signal handler. Also see `man signal-safety`. Point is, output using `std::cout` may well be a more complex operation than a mere `write()` call. In particular, there is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/sentry, which effectively makes output a critical section which you're violating when re-entering it from the signal handler.

Comment: @stark That's not an issue. All the relevant data is copied to an internal data structure in the kernel.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're trying to write an editor. There are a huge number of text editors including a huge number that are open source that you can contribute to or examine how they handle SIGWINCH. Your primary problem is that you are attempting to do things (like use std::cout) in your signal handler that cannot be safely done in a signal handler.